# How to get the poster of a publication?

Tags: facebook4j

Actually, i'm getting the post_id of a facebook's post, and i'm searching to get the page who posts it. Does the functions "getParentId" return it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post/), the `parent_id` is "the ID of a parent post for this post, if it exists." As such, it's not what you're looking for.

You can get the id of the page to which a post belongs via facebook4j's [getFrom](https://facebook4j.github.io/javadoc/facebook4j/Post.html#getFrom()) method.

Graph explorer example:

```
postId=5281959998_10151166683754999
GET /v2.9/$postId?fields=from
{
  "from": {
    "name": "The New York Times",
    "id": "5281959998"
  },
  "id": "5281959998_10151166683754999"
}
```